# sales_order_place_after not firing for admin-created orders

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, adminhtml

I have a simple custom module that sends a separate email to an admin user once an order has been placed (email uses a different template). This email is supposed to work for orders placed from the frontend or the backend.

The event gets triggered when a frontend order is placed, but not when a backend order one is placed, although the event is global.

Here is my config.xml

```
<global>
    <events>
        <sales_order_place_after>
            <observers>
                <adminneworderemail_order_place>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>adminneworderemail/observer</class>
                    <method>orderPlace</method>
                </adminneworderemail_order_place>
            </observers>
        </sales_order_place_after>
    </events>
</global>
```

And the Observer function being triggered:

```
public function orderPlace($observer){
    $order = $observer->getData('order');
    $orderId = $order->getId();
    $this->sendAdminOrderNotification($orderId);
}
```

Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong? I am using magento 1.9.3.1

Comment: Please try `sales_order_save_after` instead of `sales_order_place_after`

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your event in config.xml.
Use:

```
adminhtml_sales_order_create_process_data
```

OR

```
sales_order_save_after
```

Updated config.xml

```
<global>
<events>
    <sales_order_save_after>
        <observers>
            <adminneworderemail_order_place>
                <type>singleton</type>
                <class>adminneworderemail/observer</class>
                <method>orderPlace</method>
            </adminneworderemail_order_place>
        </observers>
    </sales_order_save_after>
</events>
```